# Parent-Child Relational Table

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, tree

Context:

- A table of transactions coming from an external system is queried to create elements on a local system with two main columns:
- A child that is not yet persisted in the local database
- Possible multiple parents semi-colon separated (which can be persisted locally or not yet created)

I'm having a problem with sorting a table that looks like this:

```
Child    Parents
A        B;C
B        C;E
C        F;X
```

What I want to accomplish is to make sure the Parent always gets created before the child:

```
Child    Parents
C        F;X
B        C;E
A        B;C
```

F, X & E in this example represents elements already persisted in the local database that could be on my query

I spent some time thinking this through and it seems it's related to trees / graphs on which I have little to no knowledge...

Any idea what kind of sorting we are dealing with here and possible java or SQL implementations?

Edit:

- Every Child Element is an element that is not persisted yet on the database
- A child can either have a list of parents already persisted (like F, X & E) or parents I still need to persist (in which case they need to precede said child) or a mix of both (like B with C;E parents E already persisted and C comes in this transaction and must precede B)
- Can not alter the database, but can reorder things freely in java

Thanks in advance

**Partial Solution**
I've adapted Joshua's solution and it seems to work this way:

(basically use like statement because we can have something like AA;BB;CC as a parent)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
s1.child,
s1.parents,
    CASE
        WHEN s2.parents IS NULL THEN 0
        WHEN s2.parents LIKE '%' + s1.child + '%' THEN 1
        ELSE 3
    END
AS x
FROM
sample s1
LEFT JOIN sample s2 ON s2.parents LIKE '%' + s1.child + '%'
WHERE
s1.treateddate IS NULL
ORDER BY
CASE
    WHEN s2.parents IS NULL THEN 0
    WHEN s2.parents LIKE '%' + s1.child + '%' THEN 1
    ELSE 3
END
DESC
```

This solution doesn't account for a child which is a parent at the same time!

**Solution Java**
I found the solution in Java to reordering the dataset, this is just pseudo code because I'm using a proprietary library...

```
private void sortByParentFirst(rows) {
for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rows.size(); j++) {
         boolean match = false;
         //parents comma seperated at j contain child i
         if (Parents[j].contains(Child[i]) ) {
             match = true;
         }
         //this means we found an occurrence of the child i at a previous position j
         if (match && j < i) {
            //swap rows i & j
            swap(i,j);
            break;
         }
     }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do? Are you querying for data or persisting data? Also, what do you mean with "Parent always gets created before the child"?

Comment: Hi @MickMnemonic  and thanks for responding I edited my post with a better description

Comment: Not at all clear to me how this table looks?   Why not just enter null for parent then come back and update?

Comment: You really have multiple values packed in a single column using a ;

Comment: Hi @Paparazzi, Yes I do have a setup like that.
I can't alter the database, I have data that comes from outside I have no control over.
I will update soon the OP with a java solution I made (basically sorting by parent first) but so far I don't know how to solve it with SQL

Comment: @IqbalAissaoui Why?

Comment: Why parents can be semi-column separated? I have no idea. I don't have full knowledge of decisions made before I started working on this

Answer (score 0):

Here the table sample contains your data

```
select * from sample

chid parents
---- ----------
A    B;C
B    C;E
C    F;X
```

---

```
select * from sample

drop table #sample
drop table #sample2

select * into #sample from sample
select * into #sample2 from sample where 1=2

alter table #sample2 add counter int

declare @count int
select @count = count(1) from #sample

declare @child char(1)
declare @counter int = 1

while(@count > 0)
begin
    select @child = t1.chid
    from #sample t1
    inner join #sample t2 on CHARINDEX(t1.chid,t2.parents) = 0
    group by t1.chid
    having count( t1.chid) = 1

    insert into #sample2
    select *,@counter from #sample where chid = @child

    delete from #sample where chid = @child

    select @count = count(1) from #sample
    set @counter = @counter + 1
end

select chid, parents from #sample2 order by counter
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use queries this complex I'm not allowed to alter the database in any way, shape or form, I need to either find a single select from the sample table that will sort it, or in java I can be more flexible because I already have the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct s1.*  ,
case when s2.parents is null and s3.parents is null then 0 
 when s1.child = left(s2.parents,1) and s3.parents is null  then 1
 when s1.child = right(s3.parents,1) and s2.parents is null  then 2
else 3 end as x
from sample s1
left join sample s2 on s1.child = left(s2.parents,1) 
left join sample s3 on s1.child = right(s3.parents,1)
order by 
case when s2.parents is null and s3.parents is null then 0 
 when s1.child = left(s2.parents,1) and s3.parents is null  then 1
 when s1.child = right(s3.parents,1) and s2.parents is null  then 2
else 3 end desc
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82ed28/55/0)

Join the table back to itself twice looking for a match to a parent.  If the real date is more than just a character, then you can use [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) to locate the delimiter and per form a left or right based off the location of the returned starting position.

Comment: Thanks! I've adapted your query to my needs and I think it is a solution to my problem!

Comment: This needs a small tweak so that the levels become dynamic( ensure the right order for an element that is a child and a parent to other records at the same time), otherwise it works great